# Game update for battlefield

Tags: xbox-one, battlefield-1

My son was updating Battlefield 1 on his Xbox one and ran out of data. It is at 58 percent, can we unplug and take it to another location and finish the update?

Comment: Adding what platform you're on would probably but helpful.  As far as my knowledge goes I think you should be able to do what you're suggesting on both Xbox One and PS4

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to do so just power down before unplugging it. I have moved machines while updating with no issues.  Worst you can usually get is a corrupted file and you delete/reinstall but again absolute worst case.